# Why is this a corollary from Hahn Banch?

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem

On Wikipedia I found that the following is a corollary of Hahn Banach:

Let $X$ be a normed vector space. $M \subset X$ a linear subspace and $x_0 \in X$ such that $d:=\inf\limits_{y\in M}||x_0-y|| > 0$. Then there exists a continuous functional $f$ such that $f(x_0) = d$, $||f|| = 1$ and $f(y) = 0 \quad \forall y \in M$.

I can consider the projection form $\pi : X \to X/\bar{M}$, so $||\pi||$ with the norm of the quotient space should have all this properties.

So is this really a corollary of Hahn Banach or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: A functional takes values in the field you take your vector space over. Unless $M$ has codimension $1$ the linear map you construct does not.

Comment: @RhysSteele I changed it, so I would consider the norm of this projection as functional

Comment: Well now your map is either a constant if you mean the operator norm or just isnt even linear.

Comment: Your right, I did not think about it, my map is not linear anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a corollary of Hahn-Banach, quite a classic one. Here's the proof:

Since $d>0$, we have that $Lin(\{x_0\}) \cap M = \{0\}$, where $Lin(\{x_0\}) =\{tx_0, \, t \in \mathbb{K}\}$. Hence, we can define space $X_1 = Lin(\{x_0\}) \oplus M$ and functional $G: X_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ with following formula:
$$
G(tx_0+y)=td \qquad t\in\mathbb{K}, \ y\in M
$$
$G$ is linear and, if $x \in X_1$, $x=tx_0 + y$ we have:
$$
|G(x)|=|t|d \le |t| \cdot || x_0 -\big(-\frac{1}{t}\big)y|| = ||tx_0+y|| = ||x||
$$
(we have plugged $(-\frac{1}{t}\big)y$ in since it is in M, and by definition it's "further" from $x_0$ than $d$). This proves that G is also an element of $X_1^*$ and $||G||\le 1$.

Take some $\varepsilon > 0$. There exists $y \in M$ s.t. $||x_0 - y|| < d + \varepsilon $. Let us define:
$$
z := \frac{x_0-y}{||x_0-y||} \quad \text{so that }||z||=1 
$$
Because $G(x_0 - y)=d$ (by definition) and by linearity of $G$ we get that:
$$
|G(z)|=\frac{|g(x_0-y)|}{||x_0-y||} > \frac{d}{d+\varepsilon}
$$
Hence $||G||>\frac{d}{d+\varepsilon}$, but $\varepsilon$ has been chosen arbitraly, so going with it to 0 gives us $||G|| \ge 1$, and we get that $||G||=1$.

Now, we do use Hahn-Banach Theorem. It gives us functional $F \in X^*$ s.t. $||F||=1$ and $F(x)=G(x)$ for every $x \in X_1$. In particular, $F(y)=G(y)=0$ for each $y \in M$ and $F(x_0)=G(x_0)=d$.

Comment: This may be a good answer, but that was not the question. :-) The question was whether this proof could be shortened by avoiding Hahn-Banach.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro well the main question isn't stated all that clear. I interpreted it as "Why it is a corollary from H-B", thus proposed explanation. If we were to read the question as "can we avoid H-B" in the proof, I'd still say no, because for our functional to maintain linear and continuous, we need finer techniques than just defining projection, as OP suggested. In fact, this is kind of a continuous equivalent of projection, impossible to construct without H-B.

Comment: My questions came form thinking the norm of the projection would be linear. But it is just sublinear. So my idea does not work for getting this proposition without Hahn Banach.