# $y\notin \overline M\Leftrightarrow$ continuous, linear functional $f$ satisfying $f(y)\neq 0, f(M)=0.$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $M\subset H$.
Then the following equivalence holds:

$y\notin \overline M\Leftrightarrow$ there existis a continuous, linear functional $f:H\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(y)\neq 0, f(M)=0.$

My proof:

$"\Leftarrow"$ Since $f$ is continuous it follows $f(\overline M)\subset \overline{f(M)}$, so $\overline M\subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(M)})=f^{-1}(\{0\})$. Suppose $y\in \overline M.$ Then $y\in f^{-1}(\{0\})$, so $f(y)=0$.

$"\Rightarrow"$ I am struggling here. I thought I could use the distant function but it is not linear...
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Suppose $M$ to be linear.

Comment: Are you sure that there are _no_ assumptions whatsoever on $M$? Like $M$ should be a linear subspace?

Comment: @Thomas $M$ is just supposed to be a subset of a Hilbert space

Comment: Then the statement is not true. Take $H=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $M = H\backslash B_1((0,2))$, say, where $B_r(p) $ is the closed ball of radius $r$ around $p$. 

So, specifically, the point $(0,2)$ is in the complement of $\bar M$. But if $f$ is a linear functional which vanishes on $(0,2)$ it will also vanish, by linearity on $2\cdot (0,2) = (0,4)\in M$ (so it's no surprise you are struggling with $\Rightarrow$)

Comment: @Thomas thank you, I didn`t think about this! If we suppose $M$ is a linear subspace do you have any advice for me on how to proceed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is this a corollary from Hahn Banch?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221882/why-is-this-a-corollary-from-hahn-banch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is a linear subspace, and if you know that to each closed linear subspace $X$ there is an orthogonal projection $P_X: H \rightarrow X$ (such that, for every $w\in H$ the vector $w - P_Xw$ is orthogonal to $X$), then you can take
$$w = y - P_{\bar M}y$$
Since $y\notin \bar M$, $w \neq 0$.

Now define
$$ f(x) = \langle w, x\rangle$$
(if the scalar product is linear in the second argument, otherwise let $f(x) := \langle x, w\rangle$).
If then $v\in \bar M$, $$f(v) = \langle y - P_{\bar M }y, v\rangle = 0$$
since $y - P_{\bar M }y $ is orthogonal to $\bar M$. On the other hand,
$$f(y) = \langle y- P_{\bar M }y, y\rangle \neq 0 $$
since, otherwise, $||y||^2 = \langle  P_{\bar M }y,y\rangle$, which is possible only if $y= P_{\bar M }y$, which would imply $y\in \bar M$.